# SSIS Visual Studio 2017 - Oracle connector problems with converted SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, oracle12c

**Situation sketch**
We have a fresh installed production and development enviroment.
We converted the packages to visual studio 2017.
Package that gives problem is a staging packing only reading from Oracle and writing data to SQL Server, no complex logic.

**Problem**
Running the package via job on the SQL Server always goed right. No problems there.

When we run the converted SSIS package in Visual studio 2017 sometimes it goes right without problems and sometimes it goes wrong. When it goes wrong it happens random on 2 different table (of 5 total)

The strange thing here is, it doesnt fail. Visual studio says it completed correctly. Only thing is, the read of the table didnt finish!

**Environment**
Setup --> 1 PRD MS SQL Server (64bit), 1 Dev MS SQL Server (64bit), 1 server voor Visual Studio 2017 (32bit only). 1 Oracle PRD server (64bit)

**At Oracle side**
Good situation (2 connection sessions are set up)
Wrong situation (6 connection sessions are set up)

Comment: What do you mean "it goes wrong"?

Comment: Litterly what is stated here.

"The strange thing here is, it doesnt fail. Visual studio says it completed correctly. Only thing is, the read of the table didnt finish!"

The orange round is still going round like it is loading, but Visual Studio 2017 indicates the process is completed (The line in bottom)

I'll try to add a picture

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. VS won't say a run is "completed" if it's still reading a table. You aren't really telling us what the packages are supposed to do and what they didn't do, or failed to do completely. Can you further explain what is happening when things "go wrong"?